# How to handle error ( "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" ) in underscore.js package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, node-modules

I am trying to `run  _ .sample(myArrayData)` to get any random data from myArrayData in `nodejs`, but sometime i am getting this error as

> "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". (_.sample() function is present in underscore.js npm module ).

How to handle this error in nodejs ?

> myArrayData is dynamic array of data and it is look like as

```
myArrayData = [{'username':'ram','id':'4123414'},{'username':'nitish','id':'986414'},{'username':'kishan','id':'98566'}, . ..];

var sampleUserData = _.sample(myArrayData) // returns any random data Eg: {'username':'nitish','id':'986414'}

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Function._.sample (/home/instaffic/api/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js)
at /home/instaffic/api/app/Crontabs/Controllers/AutoInstaController.js:6278:67
```

Comment: what's the size of array? Is it too big?

Comment: myArrayData is sometime to big.  As it is dynamic i can't able to predict the size of data.  Actually i am getting instagram users followings data and store in myArrayData, from that i am picking up random users for doing other stuff in my project.